# Php group repeated array values

Tags: php, arrays

How to group repeated array values in an array using PHP?

I have an array like this

```
array[0]=203,
array[1]=204,
array[2]=204,
array[3]=203,
array[4]=203,
array[5]=205
```

I need results like

```
[203]=1,
[204]=2,
[203]=2,
[205]=1
```

i want the count of continuously repeating array values

Comment: Show us what code you already have tried with. We certainly aren't going to do all of your work for you.

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha nope, OP needs to count sequences.

Comment: Your output makes it looks like you want this as a key=>value structure, but an array can't contain the same key more than once

Comment: Array can not contain same key more than once. So your expected outcome is not possible at all. What i am trying to say, check here:- https://eval.in/1055953

Comment: The data you have provided in question is the hint for your answer...one more hint isset() function is very useful for your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to your expected output is to create a indexed array with the associative array below it.

This will create this kind of array:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [203]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [204]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [203]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [205]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

This is not what you wanted but it is what is possible.

The code loops and keeps track of what the previous value is, if it's the same it will count up the value, else create a new indexed and associative array with value 1.

```
$array =[203,204,204,203,203,205];

$i=-1;
$prev = null;
$new=[];

foreach($array as $val){
    if($val != $prev){
        $i++;
    }
    if(!isset($new[$i][$val])){
        $new[$i][$val] =1;
    }else{
        $new[$i][$val]++;
    }

    $prev = $val;
}
var_dump($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/W2adN

Answer (score 1):

```
array[0]=203;
array[1]=204;
array[2]=204;
array[3]=203;
array[4]=203;
array[5]=205;

$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if(empty($new_array[$value])){
      $new_array[$value] = 1;
    }else{
      $new_array[$value]++;
    }
}
/*Now in the array $new_array you have the count of continuously repeating array values*/
```

Comment: This is just a much longer way round to get the output of `array_count_values`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in one line of code using **array_count_value** function in php.

```
$arr[0]=203;
$arr[1]=204;
$arr[2]=204;
$arr[3]=203;
$arr[4]=203;
$arr[5]=205;

$result = array_count_values( $arr );
var_dump( $result );
```

output

```
array (size=3)
  203 => int 3
  204 => int 2
  205 => int 1
```